# WordPress deployment using docker-compose yaml - error establishing database

Tags: wordpress, docker-compose, yaml

I'm working on a school project and can't get past this issue. I've created a docker-compose yaml file to build a WordPress container and setup. After I run the "docker-compose up -d" everything seems to run fine. The issue I'm having is that when opening to WP page, I get an "Error establishing database connection"

Here is my docker-compose.yml file. Thank you.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Comment: Can you share also the config-file from WP? Where the database connection is configired. Hide or remove your password from the db! See [wp-config.php](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the db service environment variables match with the database information defined in your wp-config.php.

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress' );
/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'wordpress' );
/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'wordpress' );
/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'db' );
```

You can test if wordpress container can access the database by bashing into the wordpress container and pinging the database container:

```
$ docker-compose exec wordpress bash
$ apt-get -y install iputils-ping && ping db
```